# Wavetables and Partials

Tags: audio

I am reading [Direct Synthesis versus Wavetable Synthesis](http://www.mobileer.com/login/reg/direct_vs_wavetable.pdf). The quote below explains code I have read but I don't get why it's a division by the integer multiple, when multiples increase in frequency. Doesn't that mean we need more samples (higher sample rate mapping to more samples for same accuracy) to deal with the higher frequencies, resulting in a larger wavetable.?

> If you play a loop of a wavetable that is exactly one period at the fundamental frequency then the harmonic partials will fit within that loop. That is because the period of the harmonic partials are the fundamental period divided by N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harmonic partials have frequencies $f_i=if_1$, $i=2,3\ldots,$ where $f_1$ is the fundamental frequency. So the frequencies are not doubled, but they are integer multiples of the fundamental frequency. But if you talk about periods, then you have $T_i=1/f_i$, i.e. $T_i=T_1/i$, $i=2,3,\ldots$. So the period of the $i^{th}$ harmonic partial is the fundamental period divided by $i$.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant they increase at integer multiples. Ah, so higher frequency means a cycle completes in less time, hence needing a higher sample rate to capture the cycle? How can this decrease the wavetable size if more samples are stored due to higher sampling rate?

Comment: The sound including its harmonic partials (up to half the sampling frequency) is already captured in the wavetable. What the authors point out is that looping is a good option for periodic sounds because all harmonic partials fit nicely into one fundamental period of the sound and there are no nasty effects at the beginning or end of the loop. This is different for non-periodic sounds (like percussion etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The number of samples per wave is reduced for higher frequency pitches so that the sample rate can stay constant.  This requires low-pass filtering out some of the highest frequency overtones before or at the time of the resampling to prevent aliasing at the target sample rate.  But normally, this sample rate is chosen so that anything above this low pass filter cut-off frequency is inaudible to humans.